# Как извлечь "скрытую" информацию из тегов с помощью Python и BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, парсер

Хочу сделать парсинг страниц Яндекс.Дзена, чтобы вытащить оттуда теги каждой публикации и колчество прочитываний. Делаю это на Python с помощью BeautifulSoup.
При извлечение HTML кода страницы кодом

```
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://zen.yandex.ru/media/filmmaking/esli-vam-nravitsia-liucifer-posmotrite-i-eti-13-serialov-5d0f25adb34feb00af5df506'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(response, features="lxml")
print(page)
```

блоки, где находятся теги

```html
<div class="theme-tags__grid"> "теги" </div>
```

и счетчик просмотров

```html
<span class="article-stat__count">13 тыс. дочитываний</span>
```

оказываются пустыми.

Позволяет ли яндекс.дзен вообще достать эту информацию? Теми ли средствами я пользуюсь? В парсинге новичок)

Comment: Там страница загружает js-скрипты, которые модифицируют страницу после загрузки, добавляя динамический контент. Beautifulsoup джаваскрипт не выполняет, так что с ним загрузить страницу, идентичную с тем, что отображается в браузере, не получится. Либо используй либу с настоящим браузером под капотом (к примеру, selenium), либо найди способ отрендерить страницу, прежде чем парсить её с bs - скажем, в Qt есть `QWebPage`, загружаешь ссылку в ней и рендер уже передаешь bs для парсинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что BeautifulSoup [не исполняет](https://www.quora.com/Can-beautifulsoup-scrape-javascript-rendered-webpages) JS код, будь то отрисовывающий страницу или получающий данные из БД. Поэтому теги не заполнены, и данных внутри вы не видите.

Используйте для этих целей [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), там точно все должно быть хорошо, так как запускается инстанс браузера, который точно отрендерит вам страничку и вернет полностью готовый html.