# Не могу спарсить весь сайт Steam

Tags: python, steam

Нужно получить значения пяти первых лотов на покупку, но при парсинге эти значения не выдаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример страницы: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AWP%20%7C%20Containment%20Breach%20%28Factory%20New%29

Код:

```
import requests

url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20AWP%20%7C%20Containment%20Breach%20%28Factory%20New%29"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
print(src)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как спарсить цену игры в Steam?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130885/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-steam)

Comment: К сожалению, нет
в моем вопросе нужно спарсить цену скина, а не игры
это делается по разному

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1432219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-response-429/1432280#1432280 Возможно это Вам поможет

Comment: Вы не это потеряли https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=1&item_nameid=176097030&two_factor=0 прошу вас заострить ваше внимание на buy_order_graph

Comment: Мне нужно получить данные из списка запросы на покупку, они же лоты

https://steamcommunity.com/market/itemordershistogram?country=RU&language=russian&currency=1&item_nameid=176097030&two_factor=0

Эту ссылку можно найти в вкладке Network, но я не знаю, как получить с нее данные, тем более мне нужен список, как в таблице, на скриншоте, то есть:
цена предмета и количество заказов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как извлечь "скрытую" информацию из тегов с помощью Python и BeautifulSoup?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012288/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-python-%d0%b8-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался